# C assign char to structure

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Very new at C, pretty much first time. I need to create a list of structures in memory and pass its pointer along as the function result.

Here is the structure:

```
struct ProcMemNode{
    int start;
    int end;
    char *flags;
};
```

The code:

```
struct ProcMemNode *memNode;
int start, end, file_offset, dev_major;
unsigned int dev_minor, inode;
char *flags;
fscanf(fp, "%x-%x %s %x %x:%x %u", &start, &end, flags, &file_offset, &dev_major, &dev_minor, &inode);
memNode = malloc(sizeof(struct ProcMemNode));
memNode->flags = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(flags) + 1));
return memNode;
```

The error:

```
 warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
         memNode->flags = (*flags);
```

So how do I, given char * `flags`, allocate memory inside the structure variable `memNode` and assign the value of `flags` to it?

Comment: `(some function)` is a result coming from fscanf() i am trying to simplify this

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're trying to save the data that `flags` points to, this will work:

```
struct ProcMemNode *memNode = malloc( sizeof( *memNode ) );
// error checking
memNode->flags = (some function);
```

That assumes you don't have to copy the data that the pointer returned by `(some function)` points to.  Assuming it's a string, and you do have to copy it, you can use `strdup()` if available:

```
struct ProcMemNode *memNode = malloc( sizeof( *memNode ) );
// error checking
char *flags = (some function);
memNode->flags = strdup( flags );
// error checking
```

If you need to do the copy yourself for some reason:

```
struct ProcMemNode *memNode = malloc( sizeof( *memNode ) );
// error checking
char *flags = (some function);
memNode->flags = malloc( strlen( flags ) + 1 );
// error checking
strcpy( memNode->flags, flags );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char *flags;
flags = // something that returns pointer to string

// allocate memory needed to store flags string,
// no need to multiply by sizeof(char) - it is
// always 1, C standard does guarantee this (**)
memNode->flags = malloc((strlen(flags) + 1));
if (memNode == NULL) // always check, malloc may fail
    return NULL;
// ok, copy (***) string pointed to by flags into
// memory allocated above
strcpy(memNode->flags, flags);
return memNode->flags;
```

---

**  C++ Standard ISO/IEC 9899:TC2 **§** 6.5.3.4 The sizeof operator

> 3. When applied to an operand that has type char, unsigned char, or signed char, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1. When
>      applied to an operand that has array type, the result is the total
>      number of bytes in the array. When applied to an operand that has
>      structure or union type, the result is the total number of bytes in
>      such an object, including internal and trailing padding.

---

*** strcpy

> STRCPY(3)                             Linux Programmer's Manual
>   STRCPY(3)
>
> NAME
>          strcpy, strncpy - copy a string
>
> SYNOPSIS
>          #include
>
> ```
>    char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);
>
>    char *strncpy(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n);
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          The  strcpy()  function  copies  the string pointed to by src, including the terminating null
>          byte ('\0'), to the buffer pointed to by dest.  The strings may not overlap, and the destination  string dest must be large enough to receive the copy.  Beware of buffer overruns!

---

You asked

### Why I can't simply `memNode->flags = flags` ?

Because that would assign just the address pointed to by `flags` to your pointer `memNode->flags`. But you don't want your `memNode->flags` to **point** to the same memory address as `flags` **points** to (as long as you want each `memNode` to have it's own flags). You want to copy all characters pointed to by `flags` to another memory space. So you could do it by traversing the `flags` string and copying of characters, one by one. But this is so common task to achieve in C that there is standard `strcpy` function that does it for you. Common implementation of this might look like:

```
char*
strcpy(char *dst, const char *src)
{
   char *s = dst;
   while(*dst++ = *src++); // copy so long as there is
                           // '\0' found in src (including copying of that '\0')
   return s;
}
```